# Como pegar a rotação contrária da camera na unity 5

Tags: unity3d

Gostaria de saber como consigo mover um objeto na direção contrária da câmera.

Exemplo: Quando movo a câmera para a direita em uma posição qualquer (0,30,0), o objeto move em direção contrária (0,-30,0) para a esquerda.

Comment: Você quer fazer isso programaticamente sempre que alguma coisa mover a câmera?

Comment: O que você usa para mover, você apenas soma no transform.position ?

Comment: isso, sempre que a câmera mover, os prefabs tb vão se mover só que no sentido contrário.

Comment: Estou fazendo assim `var rot = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;`
`transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.down *rot.eulerAngles.y);`

Comment: Só que quando instancia o prefab, ele perde a rotação que tinha e fica um em cima do outro

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui assim:

```
void Update ()
{
    rot = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;
    transform.localEulerAngles = (Vector3.down * rot.eulerAngles.y);
}
```

Girando ao redor da câmera.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve , primeiramente acessar a Camera. Tem inumeras formas, julgando que você já sabe fazer isso ,você pode fazer o seguinte :

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Inverse(ObjCamera.transform.rotation);
```

Para mais informações sobre a Classe Quaternion(Rotação) : [Quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)

Comment: Obrigada Rodrigo, eu usei isso-  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.down * rot.eulerAngles.y); Mas eu estou instanciando um prefab com outra rotação, e o movimento só está aplicando a um único prefab

Comment: você quer q todos os prefabs se movam quando a camera se mover?

Comment: Isso, os prefabs então ao redor da câmera, fazendo um círculo, e quero que todos girem no sentido oposto que a câmera for.

Comment: á sim , mas eles devem rodar ao redor de si mesmo, ou ao redor da camera?